# Is git status directory dependent?

Tags: git

I'm hoping this is simple and I just have git configured strangely, but I don't think this is expected behavior.

I created a simple git repo

```
> mkdir tmp
> cd tmp
> touch this
> mkdir that
> touch that/what
> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/.../tmp/.git/
> git add this that
> git commit -a -m "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) 679f2ae] initial commit
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 that/what
 create mode 100644 this
```

Then I do a status in the newly created git repo

```
> git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Nothing needs to be committed, as expected. However, when I cd into the directory 'that' and do a status I get the following:

```
> cd that
> git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    that/what
#       deleted:    this
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       what
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

My question is why does git think everything is deleted/untracked when my current working directory is not the root of the repo. I didn't think that was expected behavior.

Comment: You don't have those files in the directory, just as simple as that.

Comment: I don't get the same behavior. I get the same "nothing to commit" message either way.

Comment: @OP You did something wrong in between, it shouldn't behave that way. The output of the `git status` command should be the same, that is "nothing to commit, working directory clean".

Comment: I did exactly what you did and I'm also getting nothing to commit after cd'ing to a subdirectory.

Comment: Another vote for "can't reproduce"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help - I think I've figured this out. As a part of another script for my ps1 var, I am setting a "GIT_DIR" env var (It's for adding the current git branch to my prompt, very useful imho). Initially I thought that I had checked that GIT_DIR wasn't being used by git - it's not set by default at least, but apparently it is being used in some capacity.

It's still not clear to me how/why git uses this env var as the behavior I'm seeing isn't very intuitive, I may research that a bit more. My script sets GIT_DIR to the top level dir holding .../.git. So apparently if I'm in a different directory, git does a diff of my *current* directory with the *GIT_DIR* directory. I don't see why that would every be useful.

Anyway, changing the env var to MY_GIT_DIR instead of using GIT_DIR seemed to fix the problem.

gotta love env vars...

Comment: I guess GIT_DIR is used by rev-parse, which is in turn used by lots of things. The docs clearly state that if GIT_DIR is set, that's what will be returned by git rev-parse, if not, it returns the path to .git, which is the same as what I was setting GIT_DIR to. So, I guess I'm still confused, but I'll stay away from setting GIT_DIR until I understand the larger implications.

Answer (score 3):

It is not expected behavior.
I repeated your chain of commands and it works as expected.
I would double check if you don't have any strange .git directory in your 'that' directory or some weird ~/.gitconfig configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'm glad to know it's not expected. The above is a copy/paste from what I did and the directories/files tmp, this, that, what did not exist before running the above. I've also tried doing the above with my ~/.gitconfig moved aside and I still have the same problem. Another step was to add the ppa for git and upgrade to 1.8.3.1 and I still have the same behavior. Strange... I'll keep looking.